# Installing Airstream issues: how do I enable?

Tags: lubuntu, android, streaming, upnp

Talk to me like I am 5... Very light user of my Ubuntu (Lubuntu) system, my Terminal installation and configuration knowledge is basic at best.. I want to stream music and video to my android using airstream (http://www.airstream.io/download/linux.html).

Airstream works fine on my Windows systems.

The issue I am having: I have got the `.deb` pack, used package installer to install it. All the files end up in a weird circle of `bin/16/user/16/user` type of folder, many folders deep and not in `var` or `home` directory.

I have no idea what to do next. I looked around, made sure I had Ruby and everything I could think of up-to-date. But I still cannot find commands to input or a config. So basically: *What do I do after I have the `.deb` file?*

Comment: CD to the download folder and try `sudo dpkg -i airstream-linux.deb`. Perhaps clean up the mess of /user/16 folders first. Eventually, an executable program should end up (probably) in `/usr/bin`.

Comment: ok, did that, it is now just a script with a .jar. Seems to be a script but still no config.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not a very regular way of installing software. (Making a `.deb` file available for download, instead of providing a PPT, was unusual in the first place.) Now that you have a script and a .jar file, I would look for specific installation instructions in the Airstream community.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I did, mind you I'm using lubuntu, should not make much of a difference;

from the files manager follow this path:
  /usr/share/applications

Find the airstream icon & click on it. It worked for me. Just didn't seem to add itself to my application menu for some reason. Hope this helps.

Comment: this would work with the latest version of airstream, where you can install the .deb package.